# Не выходит тот пользователь который я вызвал через id

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

***web.php***

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserDop@index')->name('user_dop');
```

***UserDop.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\drivers;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use  Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class UserDop extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($id)
    {
        $user = User::where($id);
        return view('admin.pages.dop_info', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

***dop_info.blade.php***

```
@section('content')
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Имя</th>
            <th>Фамилия</th>
            <th>Отчество</th>
            <th>Номер.тел</th>
            <th>ИИН</th>
            <th>Группа.инво</th>
            <th>Создан</th>


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($user as $u)
            <tr>
                <th>{{$loop->index+1}}</th>
                <th>{{$u->name}}</th>
                <th>{{$u->surname}}</th>
                <th>{{$u->patronymic}}</th>
                <th>{{$u->number}}</th>
                <th>{{$u->iin}}</th>
                <th>{{$u->groupinvalid}}</th>
                <th>{{$u->created_at}}</th>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

***ссылка по которой нажимаю для перехлда на этот id***

```
<th> <a class="btn btn-primary"  style="margin-bottom: 40px"  href="{{ URL::to('user/'.$u->id) }}">{{ __('+') }}</a> </th>
```

**тут должны быть данные того пользователя на которого нажали см.фото**
  [![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHQsi.png][1]][1]

[![когда я нажимю на плюсик мне нужно чтобы выходила (см.фото 1 ) его данные 
][2]][2]

[![фото (3)][3]][3]

[![введите сюда описание изображения][4]][4]

[![введите сюда описание изображения][5]][5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> когда я наживал на ссылку у меняя выходил тот пользователь на котором была эта сылка и чтобы эта таблица была заполнена его данными из БД

Используйте `User::find($id)` или `User::where('id', $id)->first()` если хотите получить один экземпляр пользователя.

Если я правильно понял задачу, то в таком случае нет необходимости использовать `@foreach($user as $u)`. Достаточно будет добавить проверку на существование пользователя. После нее ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>{{$user->id}}</th>
        <th>{{$user->name}}</th>
        <th>{{$user->surname}}</th>
        <th>{{$user->patronymic}}</th>
        <th>{{$user->number}}</th>
        <th>{{$user->iin}}</th>
        <th>{{$user->groupinvalid}}</th>
        <th>{{$user->created_at}}</th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Не совсем ясно где у вас находится ссылка, но, при необходимости, не забудьте заменить код в ней тоже.

Comment: Undefined variable: loop (0) выходит такая ошибка прошу помочь

Comment: Совсем забыл. $loop не работает без foreach. Но, опять же, если я правильно понял задачу и foreach не нужен, то и $loop тоже не нужен. Просто удалите эту строку <th>{{$loop->index+1}}</th>

Comment: теперь новая ошибка Undefined variable: user (0)

Comment: Проверьте какой id приходит в public function index($id) и дайте знать

Comment: проходит айди того пользователя на котором она была нажата допустим в данный момент URL  такой (/user/71) в базе данных этот айди есть (см фото (3)  )

Comment: Скиньте весь лог ошибки. Пока что не совсем понятно. Если пользователь с id = 71 существует в таблице users, то все должно работать

Comment: надеюсь что ,то (см фото 1,2,3,4)

Comment: А если написать так User::where('id', $id)->first($id); то выходит эта ошибка  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '71' in 'field list' (42S22)       ***(может поможет)***

Comment: Во первых User::where('id', $id)->first(); пез параметра в методе first(). Во вторых вы можете удалить все скриншоты с логами кроме второго и хотелось бы увидеть на нем развернутый массив в Arguments

Comment: все прикрепил то что вы сказали

Comment: попробуйте вызвать composer update, некоторые странные проблемы лечатся таким способом. Укажите в вопросе верию laravel, которую вы используете. Попробуйте в контроллере явно передать пользователя с явно указанным id для теста. У меня не получилось воспроизвести вашу ошибку. Как вариант можете проверить или ошибка не спровоцирована  каким-то middleware. Используйте dd() https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-dd для дампа пользователя в контроллере

Comment: Если указать определенный то ошибка такая SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '73' in 'where clause' (42S22)

Comment: $user = User::find(73);
return view('admin.pages.dop_info', ['user' => $user]);

Comment: 73  выходит в той таблице он срабатывает как теперь сделать чтоб выходил тот на которого нажали

Comment: Какой той? Дайте здесь ссылку на скриншот чтобы не захламлять вопрос

Comment: она уже прикреплена фото подписано так  :(тут должны быть данные того пользователя на которого нажали см.фото)

Comment: мне удалось решить вопрос вот код  public function index($user)
    {
        $user=User::find($user);
        return view('admin.pages.dop_info', ['user' => $user]);
    }

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали по какому полю хотите искать: `User::where('id', $id)` так же можете использовать `User::find($id)`

Comment: User::where('id', $id)  все равно пусто.

Comment: а вы уверены, что в переменной id есть значение? сделайте dump

Comment: Может я неправильно сформулировал код ну скажу так мне нужно чтобы когда я наживал на ссылку у меняя выходил тот пользователь на котором была эта сылка и чтобы эта таблица была заполнена его данными из БД

Comment: я добавил более подробное обьяснение в редактирование